# Rails join on polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```
versions = Version.where({
    item_type: 'Product',
    event: 'update',
    item_id: account.products.pluck(:id)
  })
```

My current solution for displaying version changes is to query papertrail versions where the item_id is an Array of ids.

Query ends up looking like this... and growing everyday

```
Version Load (258.6ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" 
WHERE "versions"."item_type" = $1 AND "versions"."event" = $2 AND
"versions"."item_id" IN (8526, 8527, 8528, 8529, 35735, 35736, 
35904, 42293, 43000, 46408, 46409, 46410, 46411, 46412, 46413,
46414, 46415, 46416, 46417, 46418, 46419, 46420, 46421, 46422, 
46423, 46424, 46425, 46426, 46427, 46428, 46429, 46430, 46431, 
46432, 46433, 46434, 46435, 46436, 46437, 4643, ....
....
....
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Something like `Version.join('versions.item_id on account.products.ids')`

Answer (score 0):

Guess something like

```
Version.joins('join products on products.id=versions.item_id joins accounts on accounts.id=products.account_id').where(accounts: {id: account.id}, versions: {event: 'update'})
```

might do the trick. But not sure if this way is more effective on large database. Papertrail creates composite index on item_type, item_id fields and uses that index in your select. Joining in some cases can be slower.

Comment: Hmmmm... it just seems that as my product array grows(potentially in the thousands) that there is a more efficient way that just handing it a giant array of IDs to match against... i really don't know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯